# Symfony error - The "smarty" translation loader is not registered

Tags: symfony

I am getting below exception while deploying symfony application.

```
The "smarty" translation loader is not registered
```

I am using below mentioned packages along with their tags.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.4.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "twig/twig": "2.4.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.8.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.6.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "noiselabs/smarty-bundle": "v2.0.0",
    "zendframework/zend-mail": "2.2.*",
    "zendframework/zend-validator": "2.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.5.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0"
},
```

When installing these packages using composer install, below packages were installed.

https://pastebin.com/kz0LES5K

Please suggest what could be the issue for this error

Comment: Did you register smarty bundle in the AppKernel.php?

Comment: How can people upvote this question? It isn't clear, no research effort is shown and it isn't useful **yet**. But ontopic: have you followed the [Installation](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.rst) instructions? By the way: I see you're requiring `v2.0.0`. That means composer won't install bug fix release for that package. The installation instructions require `~2.0` and I think that's a better idea.

Comment: @StephanVierkant tried with ~2.0 version. same issue.

Comment: @Snegirekk Yes. smarty bundle is registered in AppKernel

Comment: My comment about the version constraint was just a side note, so that won't help you with this problem. For me, it was also an indication that you didn't follow the installation instructions ;).

Comment: The Translation extension will be registered as a service if you register the Bundle in AppKernel: https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/smarty.xml. Have you tried clearing the cache?